# Conditional check before dynamic import()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm taking advantage of dynamic import feature in my React/TS code and I was wondering if the check-up condition `if (firebase.auth == undefined)` in the statement `if (firebase.auth == undefined) await import("firebase/auth");` is necessary or is `import()` safe to trigger multiple times for the same module?

Answer (score 0):

If your project uses bundler like webpack, when you use `import("firebase/auth")`, webpack will put `firebase/auth` in a separate bundle. Most of the time it is fine to use `import` directly, because browser will cache the javascript files coming from the same url anyway, but it'd be better for page performance if it only needs to load necessary javascript files.